# Powershell: Improve class constructor for IntelliSense support

Tags: powershell, class, constructor, properties

I worte this class with two custom constructors:

```
class ExtensionApp {
    [String] $name
    [String] $version
    [String] $path
    [switch] $isContainerPath
    [switch] $useNugetDownloader
    [switch] $force
    [switch] $skipVerification
    
    ExtensionApp() {}

    ExtensionApp(
        [String] $name,
        [String] $version,
        [switch] $useNugetDownloader,
        [switch] $force,
        [switch] $skipVerification
    ) {
        $this.name = $name
        $this.version = $version
        $this.useNugetDownloader = $useNugetDownloader
        $this.force = $force
        $this.skipVerification = $skipVerification

        if (($this.version -eq '') -or ($null -eq $this.version)) {
            #do something
        }
    }
    
    ExtensionApp(
        [String] $name,
        [switch] $isContainerPath,
        [String] $path,
        [switch] $force,
        [switch] $skipVerification
    ) {
        $this.name = $name
        $this.path = $path
        $this.isContainerPath = $isContainerPath
        $this.force = $force
        $this.skipVerification = $skipVerification
    }
}
```

I'm using those Objects to fill a list i want to process later which looks something like this atm:

```
$CustApps = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[ExtensionApp]

$CustApps.Add([ExtensionApp]::new('Extension A', '10.0.2554.0', $true , $false, $false)) #first constructor
$CustApps.Add([ExtensionApp]::new('Extension b', $false, '\\server\folder\file.app' , $false, $false)) #second constructor
```

Thing is: I don't like the way i have to use the constuctors because you dont' get any Intellisense support, and if you have to mix up the constructors while filling the same List, it gets messy.

I could just define a function like this:

```
function CreateExtensionApp { 
    param(
        [String] $name,
        [String] $version,
        [String] $path,
        [switch] $isContainerPath,
        [switch] $useNugetDownloader,
        [switch] $force,
        [switch] $skipVerification
    ) 
    $new = [ExtensionApp]::new()

    $new.name = $name
    $new.version = $version
    $new.path = $path
    $new.isContainerPath = $isContainerPath
    $new.useNugetDownloader = $useNugetDownloader
    $new.force = $force
    $new.skipVerification = $skipVerification    

    if (($true -eq $new.useNugetDownloader) -and (($new.version -eq '') -or ($null -eq $new.version))) {
        Get-LogiVersion -PackageId $this.name
    }

    return $new    
}
```

and use that one like this:

```
$CustApps = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[ExtensionApp]
$CustApps.Add((New-ExtensionAppObj -name 'Extension A' -version '10.0.2554.0' -useNugetDownloader))
$CustApps.Add((New-ExtensionAppObj -name 'Extension B' -path '\\server\folder\file.app' -force -skipVerification))
```

but i'm kind of a perfectionist and in my opinion, this function should be a static method belonging to the class itself. - I also found a way to do that but it would deprive me of the parameter-names and intellisense support again.

is there a solution that would allow me to use the parameter-names AND have all the code in the class definition?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: don't use `[switch]` to type method parameters, use `[bool]` instead, will make overload resolution simpler for PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

I can't offer a solution, but I'll try to shed some light on the challenges involved:

- **IntelliSense**:

  - As of v2022.6.3 of the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) for Visual Studio Code, IntelliSense support for calling *methods* is limited to *read-only display* of *all overloads*, and is only shown when the method *name* has been typed, *before* typing `(`
  - In other words, there is currently *no* support for:

    - (a) *showing* an overload signature (parameter names) as arguments are being typed.
    - (b) allowing *selecting* one of the overloads so as to auto-complete a call to that overload with argument placeholders named for the parameters.
  - [GitHub issue #1356](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1356) discusses potentially improving method-call IntelliSense in the future:

    - (a) is problematic, given PowerShell's lack of *static* typing, though it's conceivable to let the user manually cycle through available overloads in the same way that the C# extension does, albeit without type awareness.
    - (b) *may* be feasible, if the IntelliSense feature allows calling a Visual Studio Code *snippet* in response to a user selection.
- **Self-documenting code**:

  - Since all (declared) parameters in PowerShell *cmdlets / functions / scripts* have names, you always have the option to spell out the target parameter for each argument (though there's often also support for *positional* arguments for a *subset* of parameters).
  - Unlike C#, PowerShell, as of PowerShell 7.2.x, does *not* support *named* arguments in *method calls*:

    - That is, the following C# sample call currently has *no* PowerShell equivalent:

      - C#: `string.Compare(strA: "foo", strB: "FOO", ignoreCase: true)`
      - PowerShell: <del>`[string]::Compare(strA: "foo", strB: "FOO", ignoreCase: $true)`</del>
    - [GitHub issue #13307](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13307) proposes adding support for named arguments.